# where is the "mask" node in compositing - for blender 3.1.2

Tags: node-editor

I made a mask in the masking section, but then when I went to the compositor and pressed shift a, there's no "mask" node.

thx,

-ty

Comment: I see Mask as the first item in the list when I search in the Compositor window, but it doesn't actually add anything if you select it.. However, if you select Mask from The Add > Input menu it does display correctly! Report it as a bug.

Comment: I agree with @JohnEason -- perhaps use the menu Add >> Input >> ....